# iPhone app updating based on Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I developed one iPhone application with the data which is available in Core Data model. I am getting that data in iPhone successfully but when I perform any updates in my data model like adding entities, updates are not reflected in the iPhone application, may I know the reason for this.

Please let me know if anyone having a solution for this.

Comment: if possible try to expand your question with some details and/or code. Maybe we could help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without code and details is difficult to understand what is going on. Furthermore, what do you mean

> may I know the reason for this

?

Have you tried to save the context your are working on?

```
[context save:&error];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi flex what i would like to ask is i developed one iPhone app by using core data. Now i did few modification in data model of my app like adding the entities for existing data model. But those updates are reflecting in my application.may i know the reason for this.

Comment: @user1468996 Sorry, but I can't understand what do you mean. Could you try to explain better your goal? Thanks.

Comment: hi ok sorry Flex. Flex may i know which tableview datasource method will execute automatically after that cellforrow at index path method in our tableview datasource methods. like First numberofsection then numberofrows after that cellforrow at index path method will execute in this order what we will be the next method which will execute.

Comment: you know the details of your app. we don't. there is absolutely no way we can help with such scarce details, besides wild guesses most certainly incorrect.